# Area of a circle exterior to the area of a cycloid

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving

I had the following problem:

> Obtain the area of the region of the circle with $r = 1$ that is exterior from the area of a cycloid given by $r(\theta) = 1 - \cos\theta $

My idea was just to subtract the functions and put them in the area formula. Here's what I did:

$$A = \int \big[(1-\cos\theta)-(1)\big]^2 d\theta = \int (-\cos\theta)^2 d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2\theta)$$

I don't know if my procedure was right. I think the problem statement was vague so I got confused to what it was asking.

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\sin$ and $\cos$ using `\sin` and `\cos`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the graph first.

[image]

I do not find the problem statement vague. It is asking to calculate the area of white portion in the circle of radius $1.$

Also, you have to put the limits for $\theta$ and solve. Try again and if you still have problem, have a look at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx (There are more problems in this link which are similar to this one).

Comment: Thank you very much! Then, since they don't intersect then it would be from 0 to $2\pi$ and the procedure would be almost the same but subtracting the squares of both functions.

Comment: And thanks for the link, it was very useful as well!

Comment: They intersect at $\theta =\pi/2, 3\pi/2$

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right.

Comment: You can accept it as an answer so it does not get unnecessary attention from more users.

Comment: Done, thanks again